# How Can I Add Many TextView or Other Views in ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I want to add 2 or many TextView in my ViewPager. But I have no idea for that problem. It's so complicated.

My second TextView's resource from **tipler** array.

Here is my **Fragment.java**

```
public class YaklasanlarFragment extends Fragment {

CircularProgressBar c3;

ViewPager viewPager = null;
String bilgiler[] = {"34 YNS 54","54 E 2554"};
String tipler[] = {"Muayene Tarihi","Sigorta Tarihi"};

public  YaklasanlarFragment(){}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_yaklasanlar_fragment, container, false);
    viewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    viewPager.setAdapter(new MyAdapter());
    return view;
}

class MyAdapter extends PagerAdapter{

    @Override
    public int getCount()
    {
        return bilgiler.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(View container, int position)
    {
       TextView plaka = new TextView(getActivity());
        plaka.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        plaka.setText(bilgiler[position]);
        ((ViewPager) container).addView(plaka, 0);
        return plaka;


    }
}
```

Comment: in instantiateItem inflate xml view & in xml have two or as many you want textview

Comment: yeah, but I use array and define textViews programmaticaly. Sometimes I need 10 textview. And I cant define 10 xml for that.

Comment: but your instantiateItem will call as many time as size of biglier

Comment: That's not the problem. I have to use 2 array.

Comment: If a pager has ONE textview and has many pagers?  or a pager has MANY textview and has some pagers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See Below Code that illustrate  how we can add `TextView` Dynamically into `ViewPager`. Below is `Adapter` Class and you need to set `Adapter` into `ViewPager`.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class CustomPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    String bilgiler[] = {"34 YNS 54","54 E 2554"};
    String tipler[] = {"Muayene Tarihi","Sigorta Tarihi"};
    private Context mContext;

    public CustomPagerAdapter(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup collection, int position) {
        //if Length of both array's  (bilgiler and tipler) Always remains same then we can do code like below.
    String modelObject = bilgiler[position] + tipler[position];
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
    LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(mContext);
    linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    TextView textView = new TextView(linearLayout.getContext());
    textView.setText(modelObject);
    linearLayout.addView(textView);
    Button button = new Button(linearLayout.getContext());
    linearLayout.addView(button);
    collection.addView(linearLayout);
    return linearLayout;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup collection, int position, Object view) {
        collection.removeView((View) view);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return bilgiler.length;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == object;
    }
}
```

Comment: Should I define two adapter for my problem? I mean one adapter for bilgiler array, one adapter for tipler array?

Comment: How you want to show data of this two Array one After another or mix (Like one vlaue from bilgiler  and next  value from tipler  )

Comment: No, I want to set 2 textview in 1 viewPager. When I swipe. I want to see bilgiler[0] and tipler[0]

Comment: how are you deciding which array to call

Comment: Means in first textview  value of both array from zero postion will be set into TextView

Comment: yeah, that's working. Thanks mate. Very clever move actually. I could'nt think combination strings.

Comment: But I got one question. If I want to add button and textView(for example), how can I do that?

Comment: Yes you can but for this  , I suggest you should take one XML file for listview Item and put all of your views init rather you will create TextView , Button  in IniciateItem ,Because each time you will add only one view into collection .

Comment: See my Update Answer  instantiateItem() method

Comment: this is exactly what I want! Thanks. But the worse part I must define all padding and center stuff programmatically :) Thanks again!